# How to get JSON using AlamoFire with reloadIgnoringCacheData

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have been trying to make a simple call like this to get JSON data from a URL using a custom cache policy, but I could not find a simple answer.

Any help would be most welcome.

```
func getScript(userID: String, success: @escaping (JSON?) -> (), failure: @escaping (NSError?) -> ()) {

    let url = CLOUDFRONT_SERVER + userID + "/" + "script.json"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                failure(error as NSError?)
            } else {
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    success(JSON(value))
                case .failure(let error):
                    failure(error as NSError?)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone need it, here it's a good solution

```
static let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
    return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}()

func getScript(userID: String, success: @escaping (JSON?) -> (), failure: @escaping (NSError?) -> ()) {

    let url = CLOUDFRONT_SERVER + userID + "/" + "script.json"

    ApiManager.sessionManager.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                failure(error as NSError?)
            } else {
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    success(JSON(value))
                case .failure(let error):
                    failure(error as NSError?)
                }
            }
    }

}
```